# Connect Redis using Dask

Tags: python-3.x, redis, dask

Data is stored in redis, my aim to is fetch the data and process it using DASK jobs and write to file.

Is it possible to connect DASK with redis ??

Can we stream data using dask from redis??

Comment: There is nothing to stop you from connecting to Redis from Dask workers. I suggest you try! For streams, it may depend on exactly what you want to do.

Comment: @mdurant, Looking for sample code ... :P .Kindly share ...

Comment: https://redislabs.com/lp/python-redis/